# Centering a label

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` with some text inside and absolute position. I can set the left or the right, but is there a way to set the center, so Div's text would expand in both directions.

So far I could only think about creating exstremly long `div` and centering text inside.

Comment: Do you want to centre text inside div or centre div on the page?

Comment: and where does the label show up in your story?

Comment: I want to define the div's position by the coordinates of its center without knowing its actual width!

Comment: It shows up when javascript's function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your div is positioned absolutely, you can simply set it's `left` property so that it's centered.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Some text...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
}
```

---

If you don't know the width of the inner element, you'll have to rely on javascript.

Here's an example using jQuery:

```
var $el = $('.inner');

$el.css('left',
    ( $el.parent().width() - $el.width() ) / 2
);
```

and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aa93G/ . Play around with the text inside `.inner`, and you'll see that the text stays centered.

Comment: Well, you see i have coordinates of div's center, no coordinates of its left border and the text's width isnt known.

Comment: @Alena: I'm not sure I'm following you here. Can you create a test case on http://jsFiddle.com ?

Comment: you cannot centralize something with a fixed left margin. Afterall you don't know the width of the text.

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: I don't understand what you're saying. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gDEdQ/

Comment: Take a look at this: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_-d8IC9KSirE/SsGungdzIlI/AAAAAAAAGDw/Cbuw4Oikck8/s1600-h/LabelOverlay.png The center of the div is right on the marker! If the text gets longer, i want it still be centered on the marker.

Comment: When text gets longer than the outer div, it stops working correctly. But probably i wont get anything better than something of this kind.

Comment: @Alena: Just add `max-width: 100%;` to your inner div: http://jsfiddle.net/aa93G/1/

Comment: Well, probably cause of my bad english i cant explain what i want. The idea of outer div seems bad to me(i need a lot of labels here and there on the map). And probably the only way to do it is to write a function which will show the label => check its width => place it correctly. Anyway, thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

- to centralize inner text and inline elements use `text-align: center` in the parent element.
- If you're dealing with block elements, you should use `margin: auto` in the element itself. but you must first set a width for the element, otherwise it will just occupy the whole width of the parent.

Comment: It has "position:absolute", so basically it has no parent element. And i dont know the actual width (text of the div).